# Can I have multiple ActiveItem to display multiple User Controls simultaneously in the main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Using Caliburn.Micro, I want to have something like this

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ActiveItem_Header"></ContentControl>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" x:Name="ActiveItem_News"></ContentControl>
```

so I could display in the "MainView.xaml" both User Control for HeaderView.xaml and NewsView.xaml

Tried adding multiple

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"></ContentControl>
```

but it doesn't work. Tried to change the name but it doesn't work either.

I'm trying to get multiple User Controls simultaneously in the main page.

Comment: Please prodive a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question on SO. Reading your question, it's unclear where you have defined the properties, what they return and how you map between view models and views.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `MainViewModel` is derived from `Conductor.Collection.OneActive`. This is used when only one sub screen is going to be active at a time say in a tab control or similar. What you need is to use `Conductor.Collection.AllActive`. All of the main window sub screens are going to be active at the same time therefore you don't want them to be switched off when a new screen is activated. You then need to create properties for your sub-screens in the `MainViewModel` like `Header` and `News` so that your `ContentControl` can auto bind to them.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/digitalbricklayer/workbench/blob/master/src/Workbench.UI/ViewModels/ShellViewModel.cs) for an example of this in action.